# Спорный морфемный состав

Tags: лексика, морфемика, причастия

Как надо разбирать по составу слово: настроенное (лицо)? Были мнения: на/стр/о/енн/ое, на/стро/енн/ое, настр/о/енн/ое, настро/енн/ое. Какой вариант правильный? Искали в словаре,а там нет такого слова. Вроде бы схожее значение со словом "строить", а с другой стороны, значения уже находятся далеко.

Comment: Если правильно помню, то два суффикса, -ен- и -н-.  Насчёт "строить" - правильно, по-моему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как надо разбирать по составу слово: настроенное (лицо)?.. Я учусь в 7
>   классе, у нас было задание разобрать по составу причастия, я вышел к
>   доске и засомневался в этом единственном слове и выделил приставку
>   на-. В кабинете русского есть словообразовательный словарь Фёдоровой,
>   там нет такого словообразовательного гнезда. В журнале у меня стоит
>   точка, неизвестно, ставить 4 или 5.

Если Вы в этом слове выделили приставку ***на-***, корень ***-стро-***, суффикс ***-енн-*** и окончание ***-ое*** -- то, конечно, **пять.**

Родственные слова для глагола ***настроить*** со значением "привести в определённое состояние" -- ***настрой, настроение…*** Тихонов, правда,  глагол с этим значением считает непроизводным, выделяет в нём корень ***настро-*** (в отличие от глагола ***настроить*** со значениями "строить дом", "строить отряд в шеренгу", в котором выделяет корень ***стро-***).

Корень ***настро-*** выделяет Тихонов и в производном от ***настроить*** слове ***настроение*** -- морфемный разбор этого слова у него выглядит так: ***настро/ени[й/э]*** ("Словарь-справочник по русскому языку", М., 1997).

Но не все словаристы выделяют в этом слове корень ***настро-***...

> Кстати, в этом слове "на" можно отбросить: строить гримасы.

И это правильно.  Если Вы чувствуете связь глагола ***настроить*** (родственного ***настроению***) с глаголом ***строить***, можете смело считать их однокоренными и выделять в ***настроить*** и ***настроении*** приставку ***на-***.

**Панов и Текучев ("Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь русского языка", М,, 1985)** такую приставку в слове ***настроение*** выделяют:

> ***на/стро/ени/е***

Comment: Я так и выделил.

Comment: Слава, а вас бумажная версия или  вы нашли в интернете?

Comment: _Серж: а вас бумажная версия?_ === И словари Тихонова, и словарь Панова с Текучевым -- бумажные.

Answer (score 2):

Если это лицо, значит, значение связано со словом настрой, настроение  или настроить на что-то. Значит, корень [настро] + суффикс [енн] + окончание [ый]

Если бы это был настроенный рояль, там бы значение восходило к слову строй, тогда было бы на/стро/енн/ый, но суфф. прилагат., как и причастия -енн- в любом случае один:-ЕНН-

Comment: Людмила, как раз настроенный рояль у Тихонова разбирается так: настро/ить, но на/стро/ить (дома).

Comment: У Тихонова да, а у Потихи на/строй/к/а , на/строй/щик   от на/стро/и/ть, а Текучёв предпочёл слово вообще не включать, якобы идёт переразложение, но пока не закончилось. Я тоже считаю, что не закончилось, поэтому настроить рояль пока ещё связывается со словом строй(определённый строй струн внутри рояля создаёт определённый звук), а вот настроение- уже закончилось, там связано с внутренним состоянием человека, про инструмент как-то уже в голову не приходит, только как метафора.

Comment: Текучев с нами не согласен.

Comment: С одной стороны - это старое издание, но с другой - не такой уж большой срок, чтоб закончился процесс.

Answer (score 2):

В русском  языке существуют **морфемный и словообразовательный** разбор, которые очень часто считают одним и тем же разбором, но их необходимо различать. При морфемном разоре мы определяем минимальные значимые части слова, а при словообразовательном - порядок образования слова с учетом производящих основ.

Морфемный разбор: на/стро/енн/ый.

Словообразовательный разбор: настроить - настро/енн/ый (человек); строить - настроить - настро/енн/ый (о домах);

Кстати, словарь Тихонова,  на который все ссылаются, вроде бы называется **словообразовательным** словарем.

Comment: Вера, у Тихонова морфемный словарь. И настроить (дома) разбирается по-другому. См. мой коммент. и  ответ.

Comment: 1) Серж, у меня  просто имеется в наличии словообразовательный словарь Тихонова и еще другой словарь, но тоже словообразовательный. 2) Настроиться на что-то и настроить дома -  это РАЗНЫЕ значения слов, здесь нет прямого и переносного значения,  а исходное значение корня - создавать определенный порядок, родственное слово "простирать"; 3) Нет у нас корня НАСТРО-, но есть производящая основа НАСТРО-, состоящая из приставки НА и корня СТРО.

Comment: Вера, да, это верно  для словообразовательного словаря. Но не для морфемного.

Comment: А в интернете у Тихонова морфемный словарь.

Comment: Серж,  мы же не словари разбираем, а делаем морфемный разбор слова, и корень в этом слове СТРО-, а не НАСТРО-. Ну нельзя это "НАСТРО" считать минимальной значащей частью слова.

Comment: Вера, ну я же не выдумываю из себя. Посмотрите у Тихонова.

Comment: Кажется, по этому вопросу существуют две теории, одна из которых состоит в в том, что морфемой считается часть слова, значение которой могут определить носители современного языка. Вы узнаете приставку НА и корень СТРО, понимаете их значение? Это теория здравого смысла и нормальной логики. А по другой теории, очевидно, мы имеем корень НАСТРО.

Comment: Корень ''настро'' мы имеем в других знаениях. Корень ''стро'' ( со значением стройки). На/стро/ить (дома) Но: настро/ить (рояль). Это морфемный состав. У вас - словообразовательный.

Comment: У корня СТРО 12 значений в словаре, в том числе строить планы, догадки, семью, людей в колонны, это не стройка, а создание упорядоченного пространства, в том числе интеллектуального. Вот пример: "Немного собрав  воображение в кулак...вон она, усталой походкой удаляется в толпе, неохотно разыскивая ...как бы подстроиться к окружающему".  Настроиться, подстроиться - эти слова однокоренные.  И какое значение у корня НАСТРО, его даже сформулировать сложно. Кстати, я не вижу большой разницы между морфемным и словообразовательным словарем Тихонова, кроме названия.

Comment: В каком словаре - вашем? имею в виду в словообразовательном?

Comment: Я бы вслед за Тихоновон не стал выделять корень ''стро'' в слове настроенный. Мы же не можем свободно прибавлять приставку к этому корня в этом значении. Исторически да, здесь корень стро. Но в современном языке нельзя выделять корень ''стро'' например в таких словах, как: ''насроить(рояль), "настроенное''(лицо)... Вы же не скажете "строить'' (рояль'), ''строить" (лицо).

Comment: Серж, но на месте "на" можно поставить другую приставку: расстроенное лицо. Здесь такой же вопрос, как "прибавить" и "убавить". Без приставки корень не употребляется, однако " при" и "у" выделяются как приставки. Я учусь в 7 классе, у нас было задание разобрать по составу причастия, я вышел к доске и засомневался в этом единственном слове и выделил приставку на-. В кабинете русского есть словообразовательный словарь Фёдоровой, там нет такого словообразовательного гнезда. В журнале у меня стоит точка, неизвестно, ставить 4 или 5. Кстати, в этом слове "на" можно отбросить: строить гримасы.

Comment: Денис, что думает по этому поводу ваш педагог? И что вы понимаете под ''словообразовательном гнездом''?

Comment: Можно отбросить,но, здесь, как верно отметила Людмила, корень ''настро'', т.к. причастие  связано со словом ''настрой", ''настраивать'', а не ''строить''.

Comment: При самообразовательном подходе мы разбираем слово не по составу. Здесь надо установить, является ли слово производным в современном языке (на синхронном уровне),
2) определить, от чего и как образованно данное производное слово.

Comment: У меня педагог говорит: "Вопрос спорный. С одной стороны, настроение и строй имеют близкие значения, а с другой, значения далеко находятся". Я выделил приставку на- потому, что можно заменить " на" на "рас", и потому, что можно " строить гримасы". Пошла она искать на полке словари, и нашла словообразовательный словарь Фёдоровой. Листала, и нашла "строить" только в значении "строить дом".

Comment: Понятно.Видимо, Панов и Текучев считают, что значения корней этих слов еще не совсем разошлись.

Answer (score 0):

У Тихонова есть глагол "настро/ить" (рояль) и на/стро/ить(домов).Т.е.  в прямом и переносном значении. Т.к. в вашем примере отглагольное прилагательное в переносном значении, то правильный морфемный разбор таков: ***настро/ен/н/ое***( лицо)