# Снова о морфемном разборе (настроение)

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Еще одно слово вызвало трудности при разборе. Знаю, что тема такая уже была, и ответ был дан, но все равно пишу, чтобы свою версию предложить. Вот эта тема:

> [Спорный морфемный состав](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419202/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2)

Как я думаю, в слове "**настроение**" нужно выделить приставку "на". Посмотрела словарь Тихонова. У него цепочка начинается, от "настроить", но слово вполне можно сопоставить с похожим по значению современным глаголом - расстроить.
Почему я так решила? Потому что есть слово "расстроить" (у Тихонова, например, "настройка", входит в это гнездо, а в других словарях  - нет). Как я понимаю, была такая логика: настроение - то, что настроили, настройка - когда настроили что-то, настройщик - тот, кто настроил что-то, но можно как настраивать, так и расстраивать, то есть нарушать привычный ход вещей, обычный порядок.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения.

Comment: Татьяна Алексеевна: «_Почему я так решила? Потому что есть слово "расстроить" (**у Тихонова, например, "настройка", входит в это гнездо**…)._ === Почему Вы считаете, что у Тихонова именно так?

Comment: Так написано потому что у него в словаре: настроить - настройка.

Comment: У Тихонова есть отдельное гнездо для "настро/ить". Разбираем по Тихонову.  https://sinonim.org/mo/настроить

Comment: Расстроить человека и расстроить рояль - разные значения - разные корни. Людмила о том же говорит, а она тут самый профессионал

Comment: @user190920 вот и странно, что для разных значений будет разный разбор. Вопрос о соотнесенности "расстроить" и "настроить" (человека), о том, что "настроение" от "настроить" (можно ли говорить о том, что значение "расстроить" противоположно "настроить" или нет). У Тихонова все слова включены в гнездо глагола "настроить": настрой, настройка, настройщик, а в других словарях "на-стройка", например, имеет приставку (это никак не связано с глаголом "строить", но все же приставка имеется), именно в этом вопрос. Пока что мне не дали полноценного ответа на вопрос...

Comment: Почему для разных значений разный корень, я уже проводил исследование на эту тему и у меня получился целый трактат. Там были перечислены куча аргументов и различных факторов на этот счет. Позвольте уж не переписывать все это применительно к вашему случаю (настрой\настройка). Я там разбираю полностью аналогичный случай (запас/припас): https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474051

Answer (score 0):

1. Выбираем решение **по словарю Тихонова**, что соответствует разбору на большинстве  **[учебных ресурсов](https://morphemeonline.ru/%D0%9D/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%3A%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%2C,%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)**:  ***НАСТРО/ЕНИ/Е.***
2. Нужно ли предлагать свою **версию?** Думаю, что нет, но понять решение желательно.

Есть **два слова** с разным значением:

1. **НАСТРОИТЬ**, св. 1. что и чего. Построить, выстроить в каком-л. (обычно большом) количестве. Н. школ, больниц. Н. кварталы новых домов. Н. железных дорог.
2. **НАСТРОИТЬ**, св. 1. что. Придать музыкальному инструменту определённую **высоту звука**, определённый строй. Н. рояль, пианино. Н. струны. 2. что. Привести в состояние, нужное для работы; наладить, отрегулировать. Н. станки, механизмы.  3. **кого-что. Привести в какое-л. настроение,** придать какую-л. настроенность кому-л. Н. аудиторию на весёлый лад. Н. себя на работу. И т.д.

**РАССТРОИТЬСЯ**,  св. Усиленно строясь, увеличиться, занять больше места. Завод расстроился, появились новые корпуса. Город сильно расстроился за последние годы.

**РАССТРОИТЬ,**  1. что. Нарушить **СТРОЙ**, порядок расположения, следования и т.п. чего-л. Р. ряды противника. 2. что. Причинить большой ущерб, нарушить нормальное состояние кого-, чего-л. Р. дела. Р. хозяйство. Р. нервы. Р. здоровье. 3. что. Помешать осуществлению чего-л. Р. планы. Р. замысел. Р. чью-л. свадьбу. 4. что. Нарушить строй, лад музыкального инструмента. Р. пианино. Р. скрипку. Нельзя играть на сильно расстроенном инструменте. // Нарушить работу аппарата для приёма электромагнитных волн. Р. приёмник. **5. кого. Привести в плохое, подавленное настроение; огорчить.** Сильно р. кого-л. Р. плохим известием. Письмо его расстроило. Боюсь р. отца.

***Настроить*** (1) образовано от глагола ***строить***  помощью приставки ***НА*** с определенным значением. Есть глагол ***расстроиться*** с приставкой ***РАС*** – строясь, занять больше места.

***Настроить*** (2) не образуется от глагола ***строить*** с помощью приставки ***НА***, значение слова переосмыслено. У слова с этим значением **собственное** словообразовательное гнездо.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** ([материал с форума](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/%D0%9E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA))

**Каким словарем** надо пользоваться и почему возможно **разное решение?**

Возможны два противоположных подхода к морфемному членению слова: формально-структурный и формально-семантический.

**Формально-структурный подход**: «морфемный анализ мало зависит от словообразовательного, и при членении слова практически не учитывается, что от чего образуется». Морфемы выделяются по структуре с учетом современного значения.

Формально-структурному подходу противопоставлен подход **формально-семантический**: морфемное членение зависит от словообразовательного разбора.

**Три учебных комплекса** в вопросе о принципах морфемного членения занимают принципиально разную позицию: максимально семантизированную и опирающуюся на словообразовательный разбор в комплексе 3, промежуточную в комплексе 1 и формально-структурную в комплексе 2.

**Словарь Тихонова** ориентирован скорее на усредненный подход. В любом случае нужно уточнить в школе, **по какому словарю** надо работать.

Answer (score 0):

на/стро/ен/ие - строй, стройный, строить - ладный, цельный. Связано с музыкальным строем-ладом-рядом.

А если еще немного подумать, то корень скорее всего тр-тро, от слова три, строить - объединять в целое, сделать единым~триединый бог.

НА/С/ТРо/ЕН/ИЕ

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149511/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

**Гнездо 1,**  корень ***СТРО-***

***Строить*** (построить) — это создать определенный строй.

***Расстроить*** — разрушить/**СЛОМАТЬ** этот строй.

***Расстроить*** кого-то — сломать позитивный **строй**.

***Настроить*** — построить в большом количестве, нет направленности у приставки НА.

**Гнездо 2**, корень ***НАСТРО-***

Приставка ***НА*** определяет значение слов **с корнем ***НАСТРО***-**

Настроить (на что-либо), значение **НАПРАВЛЕННОСТИ** у  приставки НА.

Звук настраиваться на образец, радиоприемник — на волну, аудитория на веселый лад, **ЧЕЛОВЕК — НА ПОЗИТИВ.**

**ВЫВОД**: настроить (создать **настрой** на позитив) — расстроить (сломать **строй**).

А как еще: ***настроить — разнастроить?***

Поэтому у Тихонова эти слова в **разных** гнездах.

Comment: Откуда взято значение "сломать позитивный строй"? У "расстроить" куда больше значений: нарушить, прервать что-л., помешать течению, ходу чего-л; привести в плохое, подавленное настроение; огорчить. Настроить  - на позитив, расстроить - на негатив. Разве это не противоположность?

Comment: Нет,  расстроить - это именно сломать строй, у приставки РАС нет направленного значения: расстроить на что?  но есть расстроить (кого/что?).   Направленное значение есть только у приставки НА . А слова разнастроить (сломать настроение) у нас нет.  Пара: настроить - расстроить, глаголы из разных гнезд.

Comment: Не согласна с вами. Тут такая же ситуация, как с "убавить " и "прибавить". такое,возможно, имело место быть. если б не было глагола "настроить",но ведь настроение от него произошло. Это не самостоятельное слово.

Comment: Для меня нет никакой разницы, настраиваем мы инструмент или человек себя настраивает.

Comment: Еще раздеть – одеть, но не раздеть – надеть. Не стоит искать аналогии: семантические пары – это не словообразовательные пары. И не соглашаетесь вы с Тихоновым (словобр. словарь)  и Кузнецовым (толк. словарь).  https://morphemeonline.ru/Н/настроить

Comment: https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Для "настроения" должно быть отдельное гнездо, а у  Тихонова к нему же "настройка" идет и "настройщик", Так быть не может.

Comment: Не стоит уходить в сторону. Я объяснила вам пару настроить - расстроить, но не услышала обоснования того, где я неверно рассуждаю. Все точно по словарям.

Comment: Вы Кузнецова посмотрите. Там рояль и настроение в одной группе.  И радио вместе с ними. У всех общее свойство - направленность! И именно приставка НА объединяет эту группу.  И у Тихонова все в одной. Все сходится!

Comment: Так если там общее свойство - направленность, значит должна быть приставка "на".

Comment: Что насчет Кузнецова. Я им не пользуюсь. Предпочитаю МАС, а там значения разные. 2. Привести в состояние, нужное для работы, наладить, отрегулировать (станок, механизм и т. п.). Настроить станки. Настроить механизмы. ||Приспособить, установить для приема каких-л. волн (радио, магнитных и т. п.). Настроить радиоприемник на нужную волну.

3. Привести в какое-л. настроение, придать какую-л. настроенность кому-л. [Нехлюдов] никак не мог настроить себя, чтобы быть любезным. Л. Толстой, Воскресение. Настроить свои мысли на серьезный, возвышенный лад ему никак не удавалось. Чехов, Палата № 6.

Comment: ОК. Я не буду вас больше убеждать.   Я вам объяснила выбор Тихонова. и Кузнецова, к тому же так разбирают ВСЕ!  Вы же предпочитаете свое решение, а полноценный ответ на нашем форуме вы так и не получили.  Именно эта информация идет в Сеть.  Стоит задуматься...  (МАС - это прошлый век.)

Comment: Sharon: «_Я вам объяснила выбор Тихонова. и Кузнецова, **к тому же так разбирают ВСЕ!**_» === Такое утверждение позволяет предположить,, что Вы недостаточно хорошо осведомлены о разборах **ВСЕХ**…

Comment: Предполагайте)  Но это гипербола, стилистическая фигура. Слышали, наверное...

Answer (score -1):

Давно уже выкладывал своё исследование по приставкам:   https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/449615/204781
В слове "настроение" - две приставки: на'с'троение.
Вот подтверждение моим словам:

> мера,   по'рядок,   пра'в'ило,  за'к'о'н;
> другое,   про'чее, о'с'тальное,  и''но'е;
> действо,   в'ещество,   с'у'щество, е''с'тество;
> любой,   к'аждый,   в'с'який,   про'из'во'льный;
> ежели,   к'абы,   к'о'ли,   е''с'ли;
> будущее,   про'шедшее,  на'с'тоящее,  и''с'текшее.

Это даны понятия одного ряда (по четыре слова в ряду).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149462/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.