Почему не используется термин "сложный корень" при разборе слов по составу?

При разборе таких слов, как наставник, наследник, настроение, воплотить  и др. постоянно возникают споры при определении корня: включать ли приставку в состав корня или нет. Иногда этот вопрос по-разному решается в различных словарях, что тоже не способствует пониманию темы.

Вот пример: Андрей Шубин, 31 авг 2023. Тихонов – убийца русского языка?
Например, в слове ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛЬ корень по их версии
... ПРЕПОДА! Хватаюсь за голову, уточняю, откуда
они это взяли? Оказывается,  Словообразовательный
словарь Тихонова.


Комментарии:  Да, этот словарь реально может мозг взорвать! Даже не знаю..может быть, люди наверху, от которых зависит наше развитие, не вполне русские..?

Почему в таких случаях не используются термины "корневой словообразовательный формант" или "сложный корень", включающие корень и приставку. В современном языке пользователи хорошо понимают смысловое значение каждой из этих морфем, поэтом не стоит называть одним словом (корень и сложный корень/формант) разные понятия.

Зачем нужно включать приставку в состав корневой морфемы? Подобная информация должна изучаться в старших классах, где она будет доступной для понимания.  И тогда можно избежать ненужного противостояния.

Смысл корневого форманта заключается  в том, что его значение  не равно сумме значений приставки и корня, но имеет новое качество. Такие задачи решаются в лингвистике, а пользователям остается только понять это решение.



Я тут сегодня наткнулся на подобное, Тихонов пишут не писал корень, а писал корневой формант или ещё что, а вот те кто якобы по Тихонову разбирают слова говорят корень, особенно это форсится в педивикии. То есть смысл корня и скатывается на сленговое значение. Прям хоть Тихонова читать что ли придётся?

Хотя вру, Тихонов наверное так и стал писать. Но это тоже стоило бы проверить. " автор действительно иногда говорит о корнях (например, на с. 19), но тщательно подчёркивает, что его словарь построен не на корневых, а на словообразовательных гнёздах. Именно словообразовательные гнёзда — предмет его лингвистических изысканий и фетиш Викисловаря, судя по его нынешнему состоянию." Вот короче что пишет человек)

Причем если взять всё тот же etymonline написанный якобы одним энтузиастом, там вполне корень - это корень, и никаких проблем с ним нет, причём корень вплоть до праиндоевропейских

А у нас прям проблема слово разобрать до корня, что ваще происходит)

ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛЬ - какой по-вашему корень?)

В общем понятно, это называется словообразовательное гнездо, а не корень, но по какой-то причине все упорно повторяют корень.

ПРЕПОДАВА/ТЕЛЬ  - так надо разбирать. А так разбирают в Сети (лучший ответ): ПРЕ-ПО-ДА-ВА-ТЕЛЬ Правильно?) Еще варианты: https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/528788-kak-razobrat-po-sostavu-slovo-prepodavatel.html  У меня корень как морфема ДА,  а как формант ПРЕПОДАВА- Но у Тихонова  это будет корнем.

А откуда термин формант? Если у Тихонова это "гнездо"?

Словообразовательное гнездо - это непроизводная морфема (преподавать) и все образованные от нее слова (5 слов).  Слово формант есть вроде бы  у Ефремовой.

А термин формант - это откуда?

Используют люди https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2413447-chto-takoe-slovoobrazovatelnyj-formant.html   https://www.langust.ru/rus_gram/rus_gr06.shtml

Нулевой формант: подносить - поднос?

ПОДНОС  под приставка
нос корень
ø нулевое
окончание   https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/russkij-yazyk-kratkij-teoreticheskij-kurs-dlya-shkolnikov-2/nulevoy-slovoobrazuyushchiy-suffiks

под приставка нос корень  - корень или формант?) Как считаете, зачем эти форманты нужны?

Формант общее название,   это любая словообразовательная единица, но  она может состоять из одного корня-морфемы или двух/трех морфем. Пусть называется сложным корнем.  Сложный словообразовательный формант.  Есть еще сложные суффиксы.

Но ведь приставка уже не выделяется, зачем говорить о сложном корне?

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/О-корне-в-слове-наставник
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476285/Снова-о-морфемном-разборе-настроение

В словообразовательном словаре под редакцией О.А. Ульяновой, нет слова настроение, Но есть "наставник". Корень слова настав.

Дополнение

В действительности Тихонов сказал то, что хотел сказать. В  области словообразования создана очень красивая и стройная система понятий и связей. Там все словообразовательное: словари, гнезда, цепочки, а также сами словообразовательные единицы. Там изучаются способы образования слов — просто с математической точностью. У Ефремовой есть толковый словарь словообразовательных единиц. Более того, словарные статьи в обычных толковых словарях также соответствуют словообразовательному анализу.

Проблемы возникают при морфемном анализе, где морфема определяется как минимальная значащая единица. Морфемный анализ изучается уже в начальной школе.  А вот специальных морфемных словарей нет, и мы используем словообразовательные словари, других и не надо. Но надо уметь ими пользоваться, этому должны обучать в школах. Именно тогда следует объяснить два разных метода морфемного анализа — формально-семантический и и формально-структурный (см. Литневская, стр. 19)..

Проблемы возможны только при анализе сложных словообразовательных единиц. К примеру, существуют сложные суффиксы -енник/еник, они выделяются в словах труженик, путешественник, и это никого не удивляет. А вот сложный корень наслед- в слове наследник не понимается категорически.


Тогда надо разбирать подобные слова на определенном этапе обучения, когда будет понятен смысл такого словообразовательного элемента, состоящего из приставки и корня. Другими словами, давать как общий обзор подобных корневых морфем. Что-то вроде предупреждения: осторожно, в этом слове сложный корень!))

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

  Но ведь приставка уже не выделяется, зачем говорить о 
  сложном корне?              

Дополнение по комментарию

У Тихонова ПРЕПОДАВАТЬ –  непроизводное слово, тогда корень ПРЕПОДАВА-.  Но пользователи не понимают этого:
 Да, этот словарь реально может мозг взорвать! Даже не 
 знаю... может быть, люди наверху, от которых зависит 
 наше развитие, не вполне русские..?


В Сети разбирают по-разному, вот, к примеру, "лучший ответ": ПРЕ-ПО-ДА-ВА-ТЕЛЬ.


Также:
https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/преподаватель
https://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/528788-kak-razobrat-po-sostavu-slovo-prepodavatel.html
https://otvet.mail.ru/question/10228097
По суффиксу ВА тоже вопрос: включать ли его в корень? В словаре он выделен как тематический глагольный суффикс (в глаголе преподавать). Тоде можно спросить, почему включать или нет?

Может, не надо спорить?  Оба ответа правильные) Успехов вам!

https://fb.ru/article/503812/2023-prepodavatel---razbor-slova-po-sostavu-skrupuleznyiy-analiz-morfem
 Как видите, морфемный разбор - это несложно! Главное - 
 четко знать алгоритм и много практиковаться. Успехов! 

Но учитель ждет от школьника однозначного ответа.

А это обсуждение на форуме (тоже не хватает "народного единства")

Наставник Настроение Приступить
Наследник

Вы можете объяснить, почему в каждом из проведенных примеров приставка включается в состав корня?  У меня такое впечатление, что пользователи не понимают этого, даже если предлагают правильный разбор по Тихонову.  А если разбирают сами, то разбирают неправильно (не по словарю).

Лингвисты занимают примиряющую позицию: разбирайте, как учитель скажет. Но не всем это нравится...  Люди не хотят просто слушаться, но хотят понять предлагаемые решения.

Мне, кстати, ответили из словаря)
